# BufferedImage very slow compared to ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, scala, swing, awt

I have these two snippets to load an image and draw it to the screen. The first one uses swing's ImageIcon:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon
import java.awt.Image

val g: Graphics2D = get_g2d()
val img : Image = new ImageIcon("image.png").getImage()
g.drawImage(
          img,
          0, 0, 500, 500,  // draw pos / size
          0, 0, 1024, 1024 // clip pos / size
          null)
```

The second one uses awt's BufferedImage:

```
import java.io.File
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

val buf : BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"))
val g: Graphics2D = get_g2d()
g.drawImage(
          buf.getSubImage(0, 0, 1024, 1024) // clip pos / size
          0, 0, 500, 500,  // draw pos / size
          null)
```

The first snippet that uses ImageIcon loads almost instantly, but if I draw it with a clip, it doesn't work (sub frame within the image to make a sprite sheet). It only works if I remove the clip parameters (clip pos / size), which makes it impossible to segment an image into a sprite sheet.

The second snippet that uses BufferedImage draws correctly both with and without the clip. But, it takes about 5 seconds to load.

I thought ImageIcon was only loading the low resolution cached icon of the file for a moment which would explain the instant loading, but I put the images side by side with the two techniques and they are exactly the same.

I could split my spritesheets sub images into individual images so that I can draw them with ImageIcon without needing to clip them, but I lose the convenience of having them all in one spritesheet.

How can I have an image load as fast as ImageIcon does, but still have clipping support?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're actually doing from the way you're presented your code. Are you executing `ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"))` each and every time you draw? If so, that's the problem, or a big part of your problem. Only load the image once, during initialization, then draw sub-images from that as needed.

Comment: @kshetline  The only thing I'm doing is presented there. I'm loading the image once, then I'm drawing the image once. That's it, nothing else.

Comment: Loading the image once, and then drawing it once, might be all you're doing *for now*, but you obviously plan to do more with this. You wouldn't be talking about using your image as a sprite sheet unless you meant to use it to draw *multiple* sprites, correct? My point is that you should think of the performance here in two parts: set-up time, and per-use execution time. The latter will be far more important than the former once you're using this in a real app, not just writing a few lines of test code.

Comment: @kshetline Yes this is right. Only, I expected the image to take a while to load because it's high resolution, yet ImageIcon loads it almost instantly at the same quality. I never saw any image loading code be that quick. I'm puzzled how it can load so fast, and why cannot it be used as a spritesheet.

Comment: I don't think `ImageIcon` waits to fully load an image, it just sets up a separate thread to start loading an image, then moves on. The argument for `drawImage` that you're leaving as `null`, which is an `ImageObserver` -- that's actually necessary to make sure such images are updated as they load asynchronously. It's not needed for buffered images, since they are by their very nature fully rendered by default.